# Why was I forced to retire early?

Tags: madden-17

I decided to try out the Player role in Madden 17's franchise mode. This allows you to control only one player both on and off the field, removing any responsibility for personnel decisions or ability to control other players.

I was playing as a quarterback. After three years I was 24 years old, 97 overall, and had just come off a 5,000 yard season and a Super Bowl loss. I had never missed a game.

I tried to simulate through the offseason, as I had the previous two years, and when it was over I found that I had retired. This seems to make no sense.

Why was I retired early, and how do I avoid it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**What I Did**

If I had been relying on autosaves, I would have been screwed and had to make a new character. Luckily, I am good about making manual saves, and had one from the playoffs. I loaded it, and simulated through each week of the offseason. For some reason, my current team did not offer me a contract extension. This seems a bit absurd, but maybe they couldn't afford me, or maybe there's some kind of bug related to re-signing, or maybe I missed it in the interface.

In week 3 of free agency, I received four contract offers. These showed up on the main To-Do tab. I couldn't find them in any other menus. I looked at which teams they were, then went to check their rosters. When I came back to the main tab, I found that the contract offers had disappeared.

I had to load again, and simulate back to free agency. I received the same offers, and was able to accept one. I've now played multiple seasons with the new team, with no further contract issues.

**Conclusions**

This is caused by simulating through the free agency period in a contract year.

When you create a new player for this mode, you are signed to a three-year contract. If you don't accept any new contract offers after your current contract expires, you automatically retire, with no way to undo it.

Once you click on the contract offers, you *must* accept one in order to avoid retiring. If you back out, the option will be gone forever.

I would recommend manually saving before entering the offseason, as this is easy to screw up.

Comment: A friend of mine had this exact same thing happen to him: wasn't resigned by the original team after three years despite being an amazing young quarterback, simulated through free agency, was forced to retire. Following this advice fixed the problem for him as well.